# how to get current page number in msword

Tags: c#, visual-c++, c#-4.0, vba

Using MSWord automation, I need to get the page number from the line number of a line of text.
I'm willing to accept answers in VC++/C#/VB.

I want to create a index of a document  for which i need the page number of the line which the cursor is presently there

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @sarath: Please explain in detail what actually you want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Selection.Information(wdActiveEndPageNumber)
```

Comment: thanks, but it always returns the last pagenumber only i need is page number of the line which the cursor is presently there